# Determining whether the language of a DFA is closed under reversal

Tags: turing-machines, computability

The question and its answer is given below:

> Let $S = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid \text{$M$ is a $\textsf{DFA}$ that accepts $w^{\mathcal{R}}$ whenever it accepts $w$}\}$. Show that $S$ is decidable.
>
> **Answer:**
>
> For any language $A$, let $A^{\mathcal{R}} = \{w^{\mathcal{R}} \mid w \in A\}$. If $\langle M \rangle \in S$, then $L(M) = L(M)^{\mathcal{R}}$. The following $\textsf{TM}$ $T$ decides $S$.
>
> $T = $ “On input $\langle M \rangle$, where $M$ is a $\textsf{DFA}$:
>
> 1. Construct $\textsf{DFA}$ $N$ that recognizes $L(M)^{\mathcal{R}}$.
> 2. Run $\textsf{TM}$ $F$ from Theorem 4.5 on $\langle M,N \rangle$, where $F$ is the Turing machine deciding $EQ_{\textsf{DFA}}$.
> 3. If $F$ accepts, *accept*. If $F$ rejects, *reject*.”

But I do not understand in the first line of the answer, in the second statement why does it say that $L(M) = L(M)^{\mathcal{R}}$, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: What does the definition of $S$ tell you about $M$?  What does it tell you about $L(M)$?

Comment: OK ... is $L(M^R) = L(M)^R$? @D.W.

Comment: Not at all, if you mean $\langle M\rangle^R$. That reverses the *description* of $M$, so likely wouldn't even be the description of any DFA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a language $L$, we define the *reverse language* $L^{\mathcal{R}}$ by
$$ L^{\mathcal{R}} = \{ x^{\mathcal{R}} : x \in L \}. $$
In words, $L^{\mathcal{R}}$ is obtained from $L$ by reversing all words.

It follows that $L = L^{\mathcal{R}}$ if and only if, for each word $x$, we have $x \in L \Leftrightarrow x^{\mathcal{R}} \in L$.